# How to use Electron remote with a helper process?

Tags: node.js, electron

I read a lot about the main/renderer processes in Electron and to me it seems neither of them is the right place for my heavy I/O based task, so I am considering to use an **additional** process.  I got this feeling confirmed after reading this outdated medium blog [Deep dive into Electron’s main and renderer processes](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2), which states:

> **So where do I do CPU intensive work?**
>
> I used to think the main process
> is the ideal place for “heavy lifting” because it wouldn’t block the
> UI. That’s wrong actually — if you do CPU intensive work in the main
> process, it’ll lock up all your renderer processes (and give you the
> infamous beachball on macOS). **So CPU intensive tasks should run in a**
> **separate process**

Unfortunately it is from 2016 and the API slightly changed. Unfortunately I can't find any updated example. I found of course `require("electron").remote`, but I miss some examples how to spawn an additional process. Does anyone have a keyword I can look for?

I use `Electron 9.1.0` and `Node 12.8.0. LTS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we need to distinguish a *CPU intensive* task from a *heavy I/O* task; with a good use of native asynchronous mechanisms JavaScript shouldn't have problems dealing with *heavy I/O* tasks.

Quite different story is when we are speaking about *CPU intensive* tasks which have the problem as said in the blog you referenced.

To deal with *CPU intensive* tasks you could find useful [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Worker) (or the Node.js implementation: [Worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html))

Comment: Thank you for your response! I would like to use the native module `nodegit`, which I would need to outsource either to the main process OR a new one. Do you have a recommendation where this would be better suited?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know nodegit, anyway my suggestion are **the** natives to deal with *CPU intensive* tasks, probably any other implementation relay on one of them.